# Combining repeating jquery function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm using the Wordpress plugin Advanced Ajax Page loader. In order to reload the script after an ajax page load I'm using this reload code to reload an image slider.

```
var metaslider_804 = function(jQuery) {
        jQuery('#metaslider_804').flexslider({ 
            slideshowSpeed:6000,
            animation:"fade",
            controlNav:false,
            directionNav:true,
            pauseOnHover:true,
            direction:"horizontal",
            reverse:false,
            animationSpeed:600,
            prevText:"<",
            nextText:">",
            easing:"swing",
            slideshow:true,
            useCSS:false
        });
    };
    var timer_metaslider_804 = function() {
        var slider = !window.jQuery ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_804, 100) : !jQuery.isReady ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_804, 100) : metaslider_804(window.jQuery);
    };
    timer_metaslider_804();
```

Since I'm using different sliders on different pages I repeated the above code for each slider, by just changing the slider ID. E.g. changed the ID 804 to 824

```
var metaslider_824 = function(jQuery) {
        jQuery('#metaslider_824').flexslider({ 
            slideshowSpeed:6000,
            animation:"fade",
            controlNav:false,
            directionNav:true,
            pauseOnHover:true,
            direction:"horizontal",
            reverse:false,
            animationSpeed:600,
            prevText:"<",
            nextText:">",
            easing:"swing",
            slideshow:true,
            useCSS:false
        });
    };
    var timer_metaslider_824 = function() {
        var slider = !window.jQuery ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_824, 100) : !jQuery.isReady ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_824, 100) : metaslider_824(window.jQuery);
    };
    timer_metaslider_824();
```

Whilst this setup works, it doesn't seem like the best way to do it, especially since I'm using 8 sliders. Is there a better to do this? Something like:

```
$sliderIDs = "804, 824, xxx, xxx, etc"

var metaslider_$sliderIDs = function(jQuery) {
    jQuery('#metaslider_$sliderIDs').flexslider({ 
        slideshowSpeed:6000,
        animation:"fade",
        controlNav:false,
        directionNav:true,
        pauseOnHover:true,
        direction:"horizontal",
        reverse:false,
        animationSpeed:600,
        prevText:"<",
        nextText:">",
        easing:"swing",
        slideshow:true,
        useCSS:false
    });
};
var timer_metaslider_$sliderIDs = function() {
    var slider = !window.jQuery ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_$sliderIDs, 100) : !jQuery.isReady ? window.setTimeout(timer_metaslider_$sliderIDs, 100) : metaslider_$sliderIDs(window.jQuery);
};
timer_metaslider_$sliderIDs();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities.

Try giving a common class to each of these `#metaslider_...` elements, like `myslider`. Then call the plugin like this:

```
jQuery('.myslider').flexslider({
    //...
});
```

I looked in the code for this plugin, and it calls a `$.each` on whatever you've selected, so theoretically this should work. (See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/PbSeC/).)

Your other choice is to put each unique id into an array and iterate through it, like this:

```
var slider_ids = [804, 824, ...];

for (var i = 0, len = slider_ids.length; i < len; i++) {
    jQuery('#metaslider_' + slider_ids[i]).flexslider({ 
        //...
    });
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, I tried the second method and it worked flawlessly. Thanks :)